# Facebook - linter gets bad bad scraper code

Tags: facebook, facebook-like, smarty, meta-tags, scraper

I have a problem with customization of data for the *like* button for Facebook. I want a custom image and a custom description. So I put some Facebook metatag in the header (under `<head>`). For example:

```
meta property="og:country-name" content="Romania"

meta property="og:title" content="Recomandare Bile 0.30g DEVIL (Blaster)"

meta property="og:type" content="product"

meta property="og:url" content="http://www.bigboytoys.ro/index.php?productID=1212"

meta property="og:image" content="http://www.bigboytoys.ro/products_pictures/16177.jpg"

meta property="og:site_name" content="BigBoyToys.RO"

meta property="og:locale" content="ro_RO"

meta property="fb:admins" content="1297430153"

meta property="fb:app_id" content="118952644876020"

meta property="og:description" content="Bile de 0.30g la sticla de 3000 buc.
```

All seams to be right for the HTML, but the Facebook linter gives me en error indicating that I have meta in body, ***but there is no meta in body***.

Actually, Facebook scrapes for the wrong data. Lines 2 to 6 are not in my source code and is just put there by scraper: `http://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/og/echo?q=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.bigboytoys.ro%2Findex.php%3FproductID%3D1212`. And so the *like* button ignores the content from metatags.

My site is served by script shop free modified and [Smarty](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Smarty) 2.6.0.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I took a look at your source and what the Facebook debugger has to say about it, and it seems like it's right...

As the message say:

> This is either because your was malformed and they fell lower in the
>   parse tree, or you accidentally put your Open Graph tags in the wrong
>   place

If you look at this in your source:

```
<meta property="fb:app_id" content="118952644876020" />
<meta property="og:description" content="Bile de 0.30g la sticla de 3000 buc. ">
```

You can see the difference between two tags, the second does not end in '/' which leaves that tag open. You need to close it.

You might have more opened tags in your source, and you should check it out. You can use [The W3C Markup Validation Service](http://validator.w3.org/), and see what it says [about your URL](http://validator.w3.org/check?uri=http://www.bigboytoys.ro/index.php?productID=1212&charset=%28detect%20automatically%29&doctype=Inline&group=0).

Comment: I agree with you that my code is not good quality BUT is not to blame for the above problem . The culprit is smarty ( my version is 2.6.0 ) which output space characters ( i still haven't find when or why ) . And the facebook debug interprets that as the beginning of the page and puts <html> and <body>. Also in HTML output view the first few characters are spaces ... I can't upgrade smarty to a new version. I can't put the metatag before the initialization of smarty since they are dynamically generated and depends of values returned by functions in smarty.  So problem si still NOT solved

Comment: You did not understand what I'm telling you. Your html is not valid, there's no way to escape that. Take for example this: *<meta property="og:description" content="Bile de 0.30g la sticla de 3000 buc. ">* Where is the closing tag? it should be either: *<meta property="og:description" content="Bile de 0.30g la sticla de 3000 buc. "></meta>* or *<meta property="og:description" content="Bile de 0.30g la sticla de 3000 buc. "/>*.

Comment: Problem solved. I had reviewed the php code in smarty found and corrected some errors . Now the facebook debuger gets right code. As for the above code, that was the first thing I had corrected . Thank you . Future plans : to include more info on og:description